# How to use the \emph or \textit in LuaLaTeX?

Tags: color, luatex, fontspec, polyglossia, italic

```
%!TeX lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extbook} % to be able to print 14pt fonts
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\Termes}{TeXGyreTermes-Regular}
\newfontfamily{\TermesIt}{TeXGyreTermes-Italic}

\newfontfamily{\MyriadPro}{MyriadPro-Regular}
\newfontfamily{\MyriadProIt}{MyriadPro-It}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\textlang{german}

\MyriadPro


Präambel

Der Zweck dieser Lizenz ist es, ein Handbuch, Textbuch oder ein anderes
zweckdienliches und nützliches Dokument
\emph{frei} {\MyriadProIt frei} % I have to insert this to print "frei" italic
im Sinne von Freiheit, zu machen.

\bigskip

\textlang{english}

\Termes\small

% \textcolor{magenta}
% The line above causes Argument of \textcolor has an extra } error
% Consequently, I can't change the color. 
Preamble

The purpose of this License is to make a manual, textbook, or other
functional and useful document
\emph{free} {\TermesIt free} % I have to insert this to print "free" italic
in the sense of freedom.

\end{document}
```

I'm translating an English text into German and I need to use different fonts for each language: For the German text, say, MyriadPro-Regular and for the English text, say, TeXGyreTermes-Regular. Inside both texts, I must use the `\emph` command.

The sample text above is only a small part of the main text in which there are many lines of program codes, tables, etc. Because the main text is huge, I can't include it here. When I compile the main text with `xelatex` it either prints some of the fonts incorrectly or gives compilation errors. When I use `lualatex` it prints all of the fonts correctly and compiles fine so I need to use exclusively the `lualatex`.

But when I use `lualatex`, the `\emph` or `\textit` don't work. In order to make the italic texts, I need to set
\newfontfamily{\TermesIt}{TeXGyreTermes-Italic} and do `{\TermesIt free}` which of course are cumbersome.

How to use the `\emph` or `\textit` in LuaLaTeX?

The questions below are related to the use of `polyglossia` package and the `\textcolor` and are not essential to the question above.

*OPTIONAL*: In order for the `\textlang{german}` to use `\MyriadPro` and for the `\textlang{english}` to use the `\Termes\small`, I need to set the `\MyriadPro` and  `\Termes\small` lines repeatedly. Is there a way to set them once?

*OPTIONAL 2*: Lastly, I need to set the `\textcolor{magenta}` for the `\textlang{english}` but it causes the error as stated in the sample code. How to fix it?

Comment: I don't have myriad but for termes use `\newfontfamily{\Termes}{TeXGyreTermes}` to define the font. Or use the ItalicFont key, see the fontspec documentation.

Comment: `\textcolor` takes 2 arguments. Are you maybe thinking of the `\color` command, which takes just 1 argument?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Actually I've looked up the fontspec documentation already but it was of no help for this particular problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to do

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extbook} % to be able to print 14pt fonts
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\englishfont}{TeX Gyre Termes}

\newfontfamily{\germanfont}{Myriad Pro}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

Präambel

Der Zweck dieser Lizenz ist es, ein Handbuch, Textbuch oder ein anderes
zweckdienliches und nützliches Dokument
\emph{frei} \textit{frei} % I have to insert this to print "frei" italic
im Sinne von Freiheit, zu machen.

\bigskip

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}\small

Preamble

The purpose of this License is to make a manual, textbook, or other
functional and useful document
\emph{free} \textit{free} % I have to insert this to print "free" italic
in the sense of freedom.

\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It solved the problem in a heartbeat. So it looks like I was defining the fonts, using the `\newfontfamily` command in particular, slightly wrongly and that was causing `LuaLaTeX`to misoperate.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you're using the capabilities of the `fontspec` package efficiently. Specifically, instead of issuing four separate `\newfontfamily` directives, I'd issue one `\setmainfont` and one `\setsansfont` directive:

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}[Scale=MatchLowercase] % 'Scale' option is optional
```

With most Opentype fonts, these instructions will succeed automatically in loading the italic, bold, and bold-italic font faces of these font families. In particular, `\emph` will work just fine.

---

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extbook} % to be able to print 14pt fonts
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%
%\newfontfamily{\Termes}{TeXGyreTermes-Regular}
%\newfontfamily{\TermesIt}{TeXGyreTermes-Italic}
%
%\newfontfamily{\MyriadPro}{MyriadPro-Regular}
%\newfontfamily{\MyriadProIt}{MyriadPro-It}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}[Scale=MatchLowercase]


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\textlang{german}

\sffamily

Präambel

Der Zweck dieser Lizenz ist es, ein Handbuch, Textbuch oder ein anderes
zweckdienliches und nützliches Dokument
\emph{frei} %{\MyriadProIt frei} % I have to insert this to print "frei" italic
im Sinne von Freiheit, zu machen.

\bigskip

\textlang{english}

\rmfamily

% \textcolor{magenta}
% The line above causes Argument of \textcolor has an extra } error
% Consequently, I can't change the color. 
Preamble

The purpose of this License is to make a manual, textbook, or other
functional and useful document
\emph{free} %{\TermesIt free} % I have to insert this to print "free" italic
in the sense of freedom.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Because another answer came earlier and it worked out the problem, I've selected it as accepted.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen - I'm glad you found a workable solution. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "another answer came earlier", though. The other answer was posted an hour *later*, not earlier, than mine.